# Python regex AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex, attributeerror

I use Regex to retrieve certain content from a search box on a webpage with `selenium.webDriver`.

```
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("searchbox")
searchbox_result = re.match(r"^.*(?=(\())", searchbox).group()
```

The code works as long as the search box returns results that match the Regex.  But if the search box replies with the string `"No results"` I get error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

How can I make the script handle the `"No results"` situation?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I managed to figure out this solution: omit `group()` for the situation where the searchbox reply is `"No results"` and thus doesn't match the Regex.

```
try:
    searchbox_result = re.match("^.*(?=(\())", searchbox).group()
except AttributeError:
    searchbox_result = re.match("^.*(?=(\())", searchbox)
```

Comment: Is there any solution if I have multiple number of regexes and dont want to except them individually?

Comment: In your code `)` is missing after `searchbox` **or** after `group()`

Answer (score 13):

When you do

```
re.match("^.*(?=(\())", search_result.text)
```

then if no match was found, [`None`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) will be returned:

> Return `None` if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

You should check that you got a result before you apply `group` on it:

```
res = re.match("^.*(?=(\())", search_result.text)
if res:
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give a more specific example of code? I basically want it to write `""` to `res` if it finds nothing. Or alternatively, `pass` if using `except`.

Comment: @Winterflags You can check `res is None`, if it is, change it to `""`.

Comment: @Winterflags Also note that your regex is greedy, it matches "abc(def" in the following string `abc(def(`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I updated the question with `if condition` and `traceback`. It seems to refer back to the line with `re.match` even though I do `if` after regex.

Comment: The regex works as intended right now, perhaps overly greedy but it doesn't produce capture errors. If it's necessary to change it to account for `None` we can do that.

Comment: @Winterflags You should check that the assigned object is not `None`: `if name is None`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to your regular expression doesn't match your targeted value. Make sure whether you use the right form of a regular expression or use a try-catch block to prevent that error.

```
try:
    pattern = r"^.*(?=(\())"
    searchbox_result = re.match(pattern, searchbox).group()
except AttributeError:
    print("can't make a group")
```

Thank you