# python | Read Data From Gdocs

Tags: python, google-docs

I just want to read a public google doc without username and password.
I have url of gdoc sheet which is public, I want to read that doc in python.

I have tried that using following code.

```
from gspreadsheet import GSpreadsheet
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1101qb2Vz0ZW7cjnTpjBpOP71wy7iOcXdqPug0F37xYA/edit#gid=0"

reader = GSpreadsheet(url=url)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

it is throwing following exception:

```
! not a valid url: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1101qb2Vz0ZW7cjnTpjBpOP71wy7iOcXdqPug0F37xYA/edit#gid=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Abdul/PycharmProjects/examples/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    reader = GSpreadsheet(url=url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gspreadsheet\gspreadsheet.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.key = re.search(r'key=([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)', url).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

**Note: I don't want to use email/password for this task.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963705/python-regex-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: no that is not related to my problem. I think GSpreadsheet method looking for a key in url but url has not key param.