# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' in fping output

Tags: python, regex

Sometimes i get this error. This is a simple ping script which parses fping output. When lots of devices get unreachable - sometimes i get this error:

```
massping.service - MassPing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/massping.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-04-09 21:04:12 CEST; 22min ago
 Main PID: 936 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: ret = self.job_func()
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: File "/etc/massping/MassPingV3.py", line 115, in dowork
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: write2influx()
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: File "/etc/massping/MassPingV3.py", line 101, in write2influx
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: influxdata = createtabledata()
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: File "/etc/massping/MassPingV3.py", line 82, in createtabledata
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: iplist = getpingresults()
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: File "/etc/massping/MassPingV3.py", line 63, in getpingresults
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: ipaddress = m.group(1)
Apr 09 21:04:12 dcoxid001prvjay python3.6[936]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

and this is not supposed behaviour. I tried to emulate this scenario, by forbiding ICMP traffic to emulate non-reachability, but it wasn't succeesfful - script worked as it should.

We're supposed to get output like this:

```
10.22.80.2   : 0.47 0.36 0.32
10.3.0.253   : - - -
10.3.0.254   : - - -
10.254.3.105 : - - -
10.254.3.106 : - - -
10.22.80.2   : 0.49 0.37 0.38
10.3.0.253   : - - -
10.3.0.254   : - - -
10.254.3.105 : - - -
10.254.3.106 : - - -
10.22.80.2   : 0.33 0.40 0.44
```

IP Address, ping result/or - (hyphen) what means device is unreachable.

I think there're possibility that i'm receiving some undefined output and the script doesn't expect that and gets error when parsing. But also i can't emulate the behavior where error appears. Script function is here:

```
def getpingresults():
        iplist = dict(load_devicefile())
        cmd = "/usr/sbin/fping -C 3 -A -q {}".format(" ".join(map(str, iplist.keys())))
        exitcode, out, results = get_fping_output(cmd)

        pingresults = []
        for aline in results.split("\n"):
                #print('Working on line: {0}'.format(aline))
                if aline:
                        m = re.match(r"(\S+)\s+:\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)", aline)
                        ipaddress = m.group(1)
                        ploss = False 
                        sum = 0
                        for i in m.group(2,3,4):
                             if i == '-':
                                ploss = True
                             else:
                                sum = sum + float(i)                            
                        if ploss == True:
                             iplist[ipaddress] += (float(9999),)
                        else:
                             sum = sum/3                             
                             #iplist[ipaddress] += (float(sum),)
                             iplist[ipaddress] += (str(sum)[:5],)

        #print(iplist)
        return iplist
```

Any advice? Thanks

Do this methos with try is ok ?

```
def getpingresults():
    iplist = dict(load_devicefile())
    cmd = "/usr/sbin/fping -C 3 -A -q {}".format(" ".join(map(str, iplist.keys())))
    exitcode, out, results = get_fping_output(cmd)

    pingresults = []
    for aline in results.split("\n"):
            #print('Working on line: {0}'.format(aline))
            if aline:
                try:
                    m = re.match(r"(\S+)\s+:\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)", aline)
                    ipaddress = m.group(1)
                    ploss = False
                    sum = 0
                    for i in m.group(2,3,4):
                         if i == '-':
                            ploss = True
                         else:
                            sum = sum + float(i)
                    if ploss == True:
                         iplist[ipaddress] += (float(9999),)
                    else:
                         sum = sum/3
                         #iplist[ipaddress] += (float(sum),)
                         iplist[ipaddress] += (str(sum)[:5],)
                except AttributeError:
                    iplist[ipaddress] += (float(9999),)
    #print(iplist)
    return iplist
```

Comment: This means that you do not have a match on the line `m = re.match(r"(\S+)\s+:\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)", aline)`. We cannot tell you, why, unless you add some data to your post. You may want to investigate what is the value of `aline` that causes the crash. Check if `m is None` before attempting to address the nonexistent groups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963705/python-regex-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: thank you, i think try/except method would definitely  help here, without going intro script details. I want to ask you. If im thinking right if i want to place a try inside that for loop ? But still lacking of skills to put that into sript:) - i tryed to write in first post, could toy check please ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's no match, in other words, fping's output not always matches this regexp. You can try to investigate it by putting the initialization of `ipaddress` inside a `try:` block, and if `AttributeError` emerges, logging `aline` to see what was the actual fping's output.