# Finding the word that follows a keyword with ```import re``` in python

Tags: python

I try to extract the word following the word "good" in:

```
lu = ["Don't waste your time with season two.  She could be fun if she wasn't so hateful inside.  Not good.*  Yuck.",
      "I only watched one episode. It had too much nudity and sex in it. The story line was good but didn't enjoy the rest."]
```

the code is:

```
import re
lu = ["Don't waste your time with season two.  She could be fun if she wasn't so hateful inside.  Not good.*  Yuck.",
      "I only watched one episode. It had too much nudity and sex in it. The story line was good but didn't enjoy the rest."]
rx = re.compile(r'good\s+(\w+)')
user = tuple(map(lambda x: x.group(1) or "", map(rx.search, f)))
print(user)
```

but the output I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

the output I wish to obtain is:

```
('Yuck', 'but')
```

or:

```
(['Yuck'], ['but'])
```

when I remove the dots (.) from `lu` the program runs without error, but I do not want to remove the dots (.) manually. Someone who can help me please

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963705/python-regex-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Regex [is not matching the first string](https://regex101.com/r/EEkxOj/1).

To handle this case, you need to check `x` for None:

```py
rx = re.compile(r'good\s+(\w+)')
user = tuple(map(lambda x: "" if x is None else x.group(1), map(rx.search, lu)))

print(user)
# Outputs ('', 'but')
```

Fixing the regular expression:

```py
rx = re.compile(r'good[^\w]+(\w+)')
user = tuple(map(lambda x: "" if x is None else x.group(1), map(rx.search, lu)))

print(user)
# Outputs ('Yuck', 'but')
```

Comment: thanks!! and to recognize numbers, how would it be? I mean that if I have ```"good#$%34; ones"``` the output is ```"34"```, but it should be ```"ones"```.